# Is there a way to evaluate the Jacobian in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have this code:

```
syms x y z
f =[x^2+y^2+z^2-100 ,x*y*z-1 ,x-y-sin(z)];
v = [x, y, z];
fp = jacobian(f,v)
```

This gives:

```
fp =
[ 2*x, 2*y,     2*z]
[ y*z, x*z,     x*y]
[   1,  -1, -cos(z)]
```

Now I want to evaluate this at, say, x=y=z=1. But

```
fp([1,1,1])
```

gives me

```
[ 2*x, 2*x, 2*x]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `subs` function:

```
subs(fp, [x y z], [1 1 1])
```