# How to evaluate a Jacobian 3x3 matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to compute Jacobian for a nonlinear problem, f(x)=0, where f(x) is a system of these nonlinear equations:

```
x^5 + y^3*z^4 + 1;
x^2*y*z; 
z^4-1;
```

I need to compute the Jacobian J(x) for this system of nonlinear equations in Matlab2009. After using these comands:

```
syms x y z
jacobian([x^5 + y^3*z^4 + 1 ; x^2*y*z ; z^4-1 ;],[x; y; z])
```

I get this:

```
ans =

[ 5*x^4, 3*y^2*z^4, 4*y^3*z^3]
[ 2*xyz, x^2*z, x^2*y]
[ 0, 0, 4*z^3]
```

How can I evaluate this? The note on this example is (Note that the Jacobian is singular for z=0)... How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nonlinear equations - Jacobian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280357/nonlinear-equations-jacobian)

Comment: well I'm not playing cop I'm just marking this question as a duplicate of another you asked a few days ago. You haven't changed anything in its formulation so it looks like a duplicate to me. No offence but I'm willing to help in preventing the exact same question being asked twice that's how this site works sorry. I would love to help you answer your question but I don't know about Jacobians. Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999561/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-the-jacobian-in-matlab) ? That might help you

Comment: Yes i have... That doesn't help me at all...

Comment: You should tell us what you actually are trying to do. What do you mean by "How can I evaluate this"? Are you doing a multi-dimensional Newton-iteration?

Comment: You *have* successfully evaluated the Jacobian. Seemingly you want to do something with it now, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: @Dave Kielpinski Which comands should I use for this matrix to prove that is singular for x3=0?

Comment: @knedlsepp I do need a code for the Newton method to solve this problem starting with the given initial conditions. As a remedy i need to implement a damped Newton modification using the Armijo-Goldstein criterion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could either write the code for the jacobian yourself:

```
J = @(x,y,z) [ 5*x.^4,    3*y.^2.*z.^4, 4*y.^3*z.^3; ...
                2*x.*y.*z, x.^2.*z,      x.^2.*y; ...
                0,         0,            4*z.^3];
```

Or directly generate a function handle from the symbolic expression using `matlabFunction`:

```
syms x y z;
J = matlabFunction(jacobian([x^5 + y^3*z^4 + 1 ; x^2*y*z ; z^4-1 ;],[x; y; z]));
```

You can then evaluate it via `J(1,2,3)`.

Comment: I get error

??? Undefined function or method 'dF' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @Casablanka: I edited the question to match your naming convention and missed the `dF`. It should be `J(1,2,3)`.

Comment: What command do i use to compute the Jacobian if z=0
I tried this:
x3=0, J = jacobian([x^5 + y^3*z^4 + 1; x^2*y*z; z^4-1],[x;y;z]), but i get this:
J =
 
[ 5*x1^4, 0, diff(x1^5 + 1, 0)]
[      0, 0,        diff(0, 0)]
[      0, 0,       diff(-1, 0)]

Comment: @Casablanka: I don't know what you mean. You can evaluate `J` via `J(1,2,0)` to get the jacobian for `x=1`, `y=2`, `z=0`.

Comment: @Casablanka: If you are asking *Which commands should I use for this matrix to prove that is singular*, as in the other comment my response is: You shouldn't use *any* command then. Just use pen, paper and simply write `0` instead of `z`.

Comment: Yes, i need to prove that is singular, and yes i can do this just using the pen, but can I prove this using Mathlab?

Comment: You could compute `J = jacobian(....)` and then have a look at the rank for `z=0`: `rank(subs(J,z,0))`. This works symbolically and returns rank 2 as opposed to 3, which a regular 3-by-3 matrix would have.

Comment: @Casablanka: To state the obvious: The mathematical reason for this is that the entire third row is zero for `z=0`.